# ASP.Net using a RegularExpressionValidator to make sure there's at least one special character

Tags: asp.net, regex, passwords, special-characters

I'm working on an ASP.Net application and I need to make sure my password field contains at least one special character.

This is what I have:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
    ErrorMessage="Password Required" ValidationGroup="vgErrors" 
    ControlToValidate="Password" Display="Dynamic" Text="*" />
```

Then I need to add an `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator >` to this field as well which needs to take the following special characters: (including a space)

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

I'm struggling to implement this because for one, I'm not too familiar with the `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator >` control and I'm having some issues since they're special characters.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you better use a RegularExpressionValidator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression to match a password containing between 8 and 16 characters, including one special character from your list. You can change at your need the range of total characters allowed:

```
^(?=.*\w)(?=.*[ !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]\^_`\{\|\}\~]).{8,16}$
```

In your aspx page, add a `RegularExpressionValidator`:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPassword" ControlToValidate="Password"
     ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vgErrors" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error Message"/>
```

In the code-behind of your aspx page, you can set the `ValidationExpression` of your `RegularExpressionValidator`:

```
revPassword.ValidationExpression =
    "^(?=.*\\w)(?=.*[ !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]\\^_`\\{\\|\\}\\~]).{8,16}$";
```